# React Test cases with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to writing test cases for React. Can someone tell me how to proceed with writing test cases for this file and how to finish code coverage.

How do i test mapDispatchToProps, componentDidMount or handleClick functions below. Can someone explain me how to proceed with steps to achieve test cases.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify'
import escape from 'escape-html'

import Message from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/Message'
import ContentEventWrapper from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/ContentEventWrapper'
import { unescapeHtml } from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/lib'
import { requestNavigation } from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/actions'
import NavigationItemRecord from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/lib/records/NavigationItemRecord'
import ScrollToTopOnMount from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/ScrollToTopOnMount'

class MessageDisplayWithSpecialCharacters extends Component { //NOSONAR

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.elementRef = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.focusOnMount) {
      if (this.elementRef) {
        this.elementRef.blur() //needed to reset focus in iOS
        this.elementRef.focus()
        setTimeout(() => { this.elementRef.focus() }, 100) //timeout needed for Android
      }
    }
  }

  setElementRef = element => {
    this.elementRef = element
  }

  handleClick = ({ target }) => {
    const { requestNavigation } = this.props
    if (target.hasAttribute('data-cui-link')) {
      const navigationItem = new NavigationItemRecord({
        samlNavigation: true,
        displayType: 'saml',
        navigationUrl: target.getAttribute('data-cui-link')
      })
      requestNavigation(navigationItem)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { messages, className } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={className} tabIndex="-1" ref={this.setElementRef}>
        <ScrollToTopOnMount />
        {messages.map((message, index) => {
          const purifiedContent = { __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(unescapeHtml(JSON.parse(`"${escape(window.decodeURIComponent(message.get('message')))}"`))) }
          return (
            <ContentEventWrapper handleContentClick={this.handleClick} key={index}>
              <Message announce={true} level={message.get('level')}>
                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={purifiedContent} />
              </Message>
            </ContentEventWrapper>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

MessageDisplayWithSpecialCharacters.propTypes = {
  messages: PropTypes.array,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  focusOnMount: PropTypes.bool,
  requestNavigation: PropTypes.func
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  requestNavigation: navigationItem => dispatch(requestNavigation(navigationItem))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MessageDisplayWithSpecialCharacters)
```

Any help/ advice is appreciated for a novice like me.

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened? There are loads of docs and tutorials out there already.

Comment: I suggest you start the unit testing from a simple code. Then, the complex one.